# Multi level menu?

Tags: theming, 8

I've created a multi-level main menu in Drupal 8, all levels need to show by default (they are revealed on hover/tap).

Unfortunately when adding this menu as a block, Drupal states:

> The menu will only be visible if the menu item for the current page is
>   at or below the selected starting level. Select level 1 to always keep
>   this menu visible.

Which is exactly what I don't want, all items need to be visible by default regardless of the current menu item.

I can't see any obvious way around this, is there something obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All links in that menu have to have the "expanded" option checked. So you have to manually edit all of them and enable this option.

Comment: It seems like a strange (although I suppose flexible?) way of doing things, but I can confirm this fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I solved that by a custom block:

```
namespace Drupal\MY_MODULE\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;


class MainMenuBlock extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    $menu_name = 'main';
    $menu_tree = \Drupal::menuTree();
    $parameters = $menu_tree->getCurrentRouteMenuTreeParameters($menu_name);

    $parameters->expandedParents = []; // HERE HAPPENS THE MAGICK


    $tree = $menu_tree->load($menu_name, $parameters);
    $manipulators = array(
      array('callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:checkAccess'),
      array('callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:generateIndexAndSort'),
    );
    $tree = $menu_tree->transform($tree, $manipulators);

    return $menu_tree->build($tree);
  }
}
```

Found this idea on http://mks.pp.ua/content/drupal-8/snippet-render-menu-drupal-8-programtically.

If you don't know how to get your own block programmatically follow the instructions on https://www.drupal.org/node/2101565.

If you did that, you can add your custom block to any region of your theme.